# Having trouble getting a new window to open with an image from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to webdevelopment and I have this function `display_image(selectedImage)` in the head section, I got a select option in the body. Can someone please explain to me how I can get the selection variable to open an image from the dropdown list.

```
function display_image(selectedImage) {

    var selectionName = selectedImage.options[selectedImage.selectedIndex].text;
    var selection = selectedImage.options[selectedImage.selectedIndex].value;


myWindow = window.open("", "myWin", "heigth=150,width=150");

myWindow.document.open();
myWindow.document.write("<html>");
myWindow.document.write("<head>");
myWindow.document.write("<title>try this</title>");
myWindow.document.write("</head>");
myWindow.document.write("<body bgColor='grey'>");
myWindow.document.write("<center>");
myWindow.document.write("<h3>selectionName</h3>");
myWindow.document.write("<img src='selection' width='85' height='95' />");
myWindow.document.write("</center>");
myWindow.document.write("<form><input type='button' value='Close' onclick='window.close();'/> 
</form>");
myWindow.document.write("</body>");
myWindow.document.write("</html>");
myWindow.document.close(); 
myWindow.document.focus(); 
}

<select name="images" onchange="display_image(this)">
<option value=""></option>      
<option value="images2/fes.jpg">Image1</option>
<option value="images2/fes.jpg">Image2</option>      
</select>
```

Comment: What is happening with the current code? You haven't explained what your issue is.

Comment: the issue is that the img tag within the myWindow.document.write has it's src equal to the selection variable. the selection variable is the path to the image within the dropdown menu. but the selection varable isnt showing the image of the dropdown menu.

Comment: It doesnt look like you are writing the value into the img tag?

Comment: do you know how i can write the value into the img tag?  I'm clueless here, i thought just writing the selection variable would work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
myWindow.document.write("<img src='selection' width='85' height='95' />");
```

to
myWindow.document.write("");

Comment: Thanx for the help, the new window is showing the image of the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

The selection is a variable and you cannot pass directly in the string. Try appending to the string using +.

```js
myWindow.document.write("<img src='" + selection + "' width='85' height='95' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

The *selectedImage* in the *display_image* function is where the object is store.

Then in the *selection* variable is where, the current selection option is set.

```
var selection = selectedImage.options[selectedImage.selectedIndex].value;
```

The *option* property of the *selectedImage* save all the options of the select element in the HTML page.

You can read more information in this links:

- [Mozilla WebDocs HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)
- [Mozilla WebDocs HTMLSelectElement.Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options)